# HTML: an explicit given url doesn´t work

Tags: html, image, url

I have two image descriptions in HTML on my local PC:

1. `<IMG src="url('myimage.png')"></IMG>  <!-- this I call "explicit" -->`
2. `<IMG src='myimage.png'></IMG> <BR>`

Neither Mozilla, nor IE do show the first image. Naturally, I tried to interchange apostrophes or omit apostrophes and so on...
Why don't browsers seem to see an image described by the 'url' keyword?

Comment: There is no such thing as a url keyword for the `src` attribute. There is a url keyword for the css background property but that is different.

Comment: Forget about the 1st example... on the 2nd: is `myimage.png` on the same folder as the html file ?

Comment: @PedroLobito I think he is saying the 2nd one works but the 1st one doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can only specify an image using a relative or an absolute URL. The `url` keyword is used in CSS to express an image location.

Refer to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp for more info on the `img` `src` attribute.

Comment: Thanks to Rick, PedroLobito,... The purpose of trying the use of url is a bit complicated, but the things are now clear for me: keyword URL is for css only.

Answer (score 1):

Some working examples:

**Relative url**, can only be used if the html file in on the **same dir**:

```
<IMG src="myimage.png"></IMG>
```

**Relative url #2**, can only be used if `myimage.png` is on dir `images` inside the **same dir as the html file** :

```
<IMG src="images/myimage.png"></IMG>
```

**Absolute url** - can be used from **anywhere**

```
<IMG src="http://something.com/images/myimage.png"></IMG>
```

The same as the above, without including the website, **must be used inside domain something.com**

```
<IMG src="/images/myimage.png"></IMG>
```